# Backbone.js not registering Model.hasChanged event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to get a View in [`Backbone.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) to save when there's a 'change' event if (and only if) the data has changed.

Long story short, I've a 'change' event set on the View that calls this:

```
function changed_event() {
  log.debug("Before: " + this.model.get('name')) // not 'contrived!'
  this.model.set({'name': 'contrived!'});
  log.debug("After: " + this.model.get('name')) // 'contrived!'

  if (this.model.hasChanged()) {
      alert("This is never called.");
  }
}
```

I'd like to know why the `model.hasChanged()` is `false` when clearly the model has been changed.

I'm not sure what other information is necessary, but if there is more information that may be helpful please comment and I'll elaborate.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By calling `model.set`, you are firing a change event. `.hasChanged()` returns true iff the model has changed *since the last change event*. So it will return false since nothing changed since that change event. To get the behaviour you want, call `.set` with the `silent` option: `this.model.set({'name': 'contrived!'}, {silent: true})`

Comment: This is correct but is easily misinterpreted.  It appears that Brian and I both wanted a list of properties that changed since the last sync.

Comment: I also want a way of tracking which attributes have changed.  One would think `_previousAttributes` would track this, but they also get updated with set.

Comment: If you want to save a list of the attributes that changed and have that list persist, create a handler for the changed event where you do something like this.previousChangedAttrs = this.changedAttributes(). Then you can check previousChangedAttrs any time you like. Keep in mind that the change event fires every time you call set() without the silent option, so multiple calls to set will reset previousChangedAttrs. If you want you can create an array and track a history of changes. Makes me think about rolling my own client-side undo system...

Comment: By the way, this is the correct answer and should be marked as such.